# Content between {exp:channel:entries} tags won't show up

Tags: ee2, structure

First, I'm on EE v2.3.1 using Structure v3.0

1. I have a channel called "statics"
2. The "statics" channel uses a field group called "statics_fields" which just has a textarea field called "body" in it.
3. The "statics" channel uses a template group called "statics_templates" and by default uses "statics_templates/plain"
4. Everything outside {exp:channel:entries} tag shows up, and nothing inside it does:

```
    {embed="template_html/header" body_class="about_bg"}
        {exp:structure:breadcrumb here_as_title="yes"}{/exp:structure:breadcrumb}
            {embed="template_html/left_nav"}
                    THIS SHOWS UP
                    {exp:channel:entries channel="statics"}
                        NOTHING IN HERE SHOWS UP
                        {title}
                        {body}
                    {/exp:channel:entries}
    {embed="template_html/footer"}
```

- This happens for every new static page regardless of if it's in the "statics" channel.
- Using Structure to move it under a new parent doesn't fix it.
- Using Structure to move it up to it's own level without a parent also doesn't work.
- No errors show up in the debug output.
- No errors show up in the php error log.
- The {exp:channel:entries} tag is not nested.

So the question, of course, is:

**Why is this broken and how can I fix it?**

Comment: Have you tried adding dynamic="no"?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4):

As Josh suggests in the comments, give this a whirl:

`{exp:channel:entries channel="statics" dynamic="no"}`

Comment: Sorry it took so long to answer, but no that doesn't work either. It changes nothing.

Comment: Try embedding the `channel:entries` loop in a different template and using `{embed="..."}`